# Simple javascript NestedSortableWidget (drag&drop) onchange doesn't work

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, onchange

I use [NestedSortableWidget](http://code.google.com/p/nestedsortables/wiki/NestedSortableWidgetDocumentation). I use this scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/interface-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/inestedsortable.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#spans-divs-regular').Sortable(
    {
        accept: 'page-item4',
        opacity: 0.8,
        helperclass: 'helper',
        onChange: function(serialized) {
        $('#left-to-right-ser').html("sds:" + serialized[0].hash);
        }       
    }
);
        });
</script>
```

I doesn't need nested items but sortable. I only need to send postback to save items' state. So when I use `$('#spans-divs-regular').Sortable` onchange doesn't work. But if use `$('#spans-divs-regular').NestedSortable` onchange works only when I change nesting elements.

Here is my simple html page: [source_html](http://www.mediafire.com/?akfbdqczauvpk3a). I need your help.

Comment: You solved your problem o not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I solved this problem a long time ago. So I don't remember the solution very well. 
But I found my final script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('#spans-divs-regular').Sortable(
            {
                accept: 'page-item4',
                opacity: 0.8,
                helperclass: 'helper',
                onChange: function(serialized) {                  
                     $.post('/Persons/PersonViewOrderList?sort', serialized[0].hash + '');
                },
                autoScroll: true,
                handle: '.sort-handle',
                fx:300,
                revert: true
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i used inestedsortable plugin with which i can easily get the id of dragged item and its parent